# How to use wget to download files that begins with a known expression and have a certain date after some unknown words?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, download, wget

I'm trying to download all files of a specific date of a ftp directory usin wget.

The pathname of these files begins as follows:

ftp://nrt.cmems-du.eu/Core/WAVE_GLO_WAV_L3_SWH_NRT_OBSERVATIONS_014_001/dataset-wav-alti-l3-swh-rt-global-al/2018/10/global_vavh_l3_rt_al_C****_P****_20181002

The problem is that each file has different numbers on the spaces where I put *.

So, I want to skip this part of the pathname and specify only the begining of the filename and the date. I know that it is exactly four numbers after letter C and four numbers after letter P.
I tried using **** or ???? and it doesn't work.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is more text after the date in the file name, you need to add a `*` after the date, like this (not including the full URL here):

```
global_vavh_l3_rt_al_C*_P*_20181002*.nc
```

Note that this relies on server-side directory listing (the FTP `LIST` command).  It may not always work because the `LIST` command can be blocked on the server side, or the server produces output that wget cannot process. (The output format sadly is not standardized.)